# postgis How do I find results within a given bounding box that are close to the center?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm learning postgis and saw that there is `ST_MakeEnvelope` to which I can pass my bounding box coordinates:

`ST_MakeEnvelope(${params.swLng},${params.swLat},${params.neLng},${params.neLat}, 4326)`

However, is there a way to get the results that are closest to the center of the bounding box?  Is it possible to combine the bounding box with a radius query?

Comment: Please tell us more about your intended query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order by [distance](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html) between your geometries and the centroid of the envelope

```sql
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE st_intersects(geom, ST_makeEnvelope(...))
ORDER BY geom <-> st_centroid(ST_makeEnvelope(...))
```